# Jquery - Input name value not changing but id is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm trying to change the value of this HTML code by using input name:

```
<input class="string required" first_and_last="true" id="high_billing_name" name="high[billing_name]" required="required" size="20" type="text">
```

When I use the Input id to change the value it works:

```
$("#high_billing_name").val('NAME');
```

But I'm trying to change the value using the name instead of the id. I've tried `$('input[name="high[billing_name]"]').val("NAME");`and other forms of that but it doesn't work.

Comment: `$('input[name="high[billing_name]"]').val("NAME");` should work. Nothing wrong with code fragment

Comment: works fine here https://plnkr.co/edit/OZuhBC7BokYma3EEXq3U?p=preview

Comment: It does work...

Comment: as you have it in your example it should work. Is it possible that another input exists with same name?

Comment: If there are multiple elements with the same name, they all should get the value "NAME". I don't think this is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `$('input[name=\"high[billing_name]\"]').val("NAME");`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends on the jquery version or even browser version? The syntax you use should work.

```
$('input[name="high[billing_name]"]').val("NAME")
```

I created a simple fiddle for it and this one works for me in Chrome 54.

https://jsfiddle.net/mpdozfqc/

Answer (score 0):

This example is using JQuery, it is straight forward:

```js
$('input[name="high[billing_name]"]').val("Johnny Bravo");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="string required" first_and_last="true" id="high_billing_name" name="high[billing_name]" required="required" size="20" type="text">
```

Also, this version using JQuery, but I use `\` to print the `"`:

```js
$('input[name=\"high[billing_name]\"]').val("Johnny Bravo");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="string required" first_and_last="true" id="high_billing_name" name="high[billing_name]" required="required" size="20" type="text">
```

But this one is using pure javascript:

```js
var imput = document.getElementById("high_billing_name");
imput.value = "Johnny Bravo";
```

```html
<input class="string required" first_and_last="true" id="high_billing_name" name="high[billing_name]" required="required" size="20" type="text">
```